# Is it possible to use git to apply temporary changes for testing purposes

Tags: git, testing, temp

I have a bunch of changes to the code in one of my branches. All of these changes have to do with a carefully set-up testing state. Now I want to remove all of these changes because I'm working on something else and the changes are getting in the way. I want the changes to be available to be in the future for testing purposes. Possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You describe the job of `git stash` here.

On your branch, simply type:

```
git stash
```

Then checkout the other branch, work work work, commit commit commit, and back on your testing branch:

```
git stash pop
```

You have plenty of options to `git stash`, so `git help stash` is recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There is 2 ways. If your changes is not committed yet - create new branch testFeature and commit into this branch. when you finish your feature, you'll merge this branch into master.
or even more simpler. just use `git stash` for that temporary stuff.